# window.location.hash = ""; forces frameset reload on Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, frameset

I have the following page:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var src = hash.substring(1); //remove #
    window.location.hash = "";
    if(src != ''){
      frames['principal'].document.location.href = decodeURIComponent(src);
    }
  });  
</script>
</head>
<frameset rows="18%,*" class="pagecontainer">
  <frame name="top" noresize src="site/paginatop.htm" target="top" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"/>
  <frameset cols="11%,*">
    <frame name="lateral" noresize src="site/paginalateral.htm" target="lateral" frameborder="0"/>
    <frame name="principal" id="principal" noresize src="site/paginahome.htm" target="principal" frameborder="0"/>
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

When I load the page with an URL in the hash, the hash is loaded within the frame[principal].
However, when I clear the Hash (window.location.hash = "";), Chrome and Safari reload the page, so the frame[principal] gets the default value (site/paginahome.htm).
I already found a bug that reports that behaviour https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24578
Any workaround would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED**
I found a solution for my problem with **window.history.replaceState**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var src = getHash();
  if(src != ''){
    frames['principal'].document.location.href = decodeURIComponent(src);
    var strBrowser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (strBrowser.indexOf('chrome') > 0 || strBrowser.indexOf('safari') > 0) {
      if(history.pushState) {
        window.history.replaceState(null, window.document.title, '#');
      }
    }
    else {
      window.location.hash = "";
    }
  }
  setFavicon();
});
```

Comment: Try shortening the question to the important points.

Comment: @ColBeseder Thanks for the tip. Already Edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, `window.location.hash = ""` does not reload the page. It just scrolls it top the top.

But perhaps using POST would be a better solution to your problem than hash.

Comment: You are half-right! I made a simple test on chrome with buttons that add and remove hashes, and it does not reload. This made me even more desperate on my problem, and allowed me to find the cause! On frameset, it does reload! [link](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24578)